# Get DateTime in this format: 2018-10-26T16:44:38+01:00

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting, datetimeoffset

I am having trouble getting `DateTime.UtcNow` to correctly format as `2018-10-26T16:44:38+01:00`. I have tried the code below, but it outputs different from what I expect:

```
DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you this format DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK"). https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to look at this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) on the strings available; to answer your question as straightforward as you asked it:

```
string time = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

Just in case the link provided ever breaks; I've included descriptions of the format strings used in my answer:

```
dd   - Provides a double digit day 01 - 31.
HH   - Provides a double digit hour 00 - 23.
MM   - Provides a double digit month 01 - 12.
mm   - Provides a double digit minute 00 - 59.
ss   - Provides a double digit second 00 - 59.
yyyy - Provides a four digit year 0000 - 9999.
zzz  - Provides the hours and minutes offset from UTC.
```

Comment: You probably want HH as hour, in 24 format (as no am/pm was specified)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing That is true, but considering most people don't use 24 hour times I went with what is most common. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: That depends on where "most people" are . And (as I just saw) the OP *did* use 16 as hour value ...

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Well look at that :) I'll update yet again!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

Please note that you must use uppercase "HH" for 24-hour format.

Microsoft official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: You can't use `z` with `Utc` time. Only local time zones.

Comment: Indeed, that's why you must first use ToLocalTime().

Comment: Yeah it went a little weird on me for a minute. Yes, `ToLocalTime` solves that issue!